# How may I quell the fungus among-us?

Tags: lawn

Sorry for the pun, couldn't resist.

Recently with all the rain (wish I could send some to Cali, they need it more than we do) I've had a mushroom issue in the back yard. There's a big discolored circle in the middle of the yard, with mushroom caps that grow and sprout on the perimeter of this circle after a heavy rain. The grass in the circle is a few shades darker than the surrounding grass, and the circle seems to be growing slightly larger month by month.

Some quick searches online didn't give me much hope. So far I've just been pulling the mushrooms that sprout to not give more spores any chance, but I realizing I'm only "treating" one very small symptom.  Spiked shoes to aerate? Antifungal application?

Comment: You have what's known as a "fairy ring". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_ring

Answer (score 4):

You have [fairy ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairy_ring) (possibly the [Scotch Bonnet Mushroom, *Marasmius oreades*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_bonnet_(mushroom)), but there are quite a few mushrooms with this growth habit).  This is a common lawn trouble, which can be treated several ways. The easiest is to apply a fungicide like [azoxystrobin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azoxystrobin), but this provides mixed results, and is not completely reliable.

You could dig out the entire ring, and replace the soil therein, but I don't recommend doing that, it's a lot of work.

Also, you should fertilize the lawn in the center of the ring, or it will burn out on the quick energy supplied by the fungus, and die in the center. Give it some nitrogen for a while, and wean it back to normal conditions. Spiked shoes are generally good for the lawn, and fun to use, but not very effective against fairy ring. However, a plugger will be very beneficial, as it will force holes through the top layer of mycelium, letting water through, and helping keep the grass from browning.

[Here is some relevant information](http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/TOOLS/TURF/PESTS/disfairy.html):

> #### Hosts
>
> All turfgrass species
>
> #### Symptoms
>
> Fairy ring symptoms vary depending on the species of fungus. A dark green band of turf may develop in a circle or semi-circle, or a ring of brown, dying grass may occur. Mushrooms may or may not be present. White, fungal mycelia may be observed under the thatch layer.
>
> #### Conditions favoring disease
>
> Soils with a thick thatch layer or undecomposed organic matter favor disease development. Lawns with low fertility or insufficient water tend to have more damage than lawns with adequate fertilizer and water.
>
> #### Prevention and management
>
> Apply adequate nitrogen to mask symptoms and increase activity of beneficial soil organisms. To improve water penetration, aerate and water heavily in holes for several days. Dethatch the lawn if the thatch layer is more than 1/2 inch (1.2 cm) thick. Rake mushrooms to improve the appearance of the turf. Dig out the turf and root zone that contains a white, cottony mass to a depth of 12 inches (30 cm) and 2 ft (60 cm) beyond the outer edge of the ring. Refill the area with clean soil and reseed or re-sod. Fungicides are available but they have not been observed to reliably control fairy ring.

Below are some pictures of some of the common visible symptoms of fairy ring:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The mycelia will be just as active when the fruiting bodies aren't emerging, and it's commonly seen in that form.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully it's not Marasmius oreades - that would make it a Grade I fairy ring, which is really not good news. You can tell if it is though - you'll see what appears to be a double ring - an inner green ring, with a yellowish deadish looking ring next, with a greener ring round the outside which contains the mushrooms themselves. The yellow deadish ring is where the mycelium from the fungus waterproof the soil, so rain can't penetrate, which also means any watered on treatments won't work. There is no real cure for any fairy ring, but in the case of Marasmius oreades, if you are so inclined, you can dig out to a foot deep and a foot outside the inner and outer edges of the ring, remove all the earth well away from the garden and replace with clean topsoil and resow the area.

If you've just got darker grass in the centre, then its a Grade II ring, caused by other varieties of fungi. That doesn't have a cure either, but it is more manageable because you don't get the dead area. When the mushrooms are present, it may be unsightly, but you can obviate the different green coloured areas by regularly feeding the rest of the grass to keep it greener.

Comment: However, if it is Marasmius oreades, and you don't treat your lawn with noxious chemicals, you can eat the mushrooms!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotch_bonnet_%28mushroom%29